# how to compile header files in c in visual studio code

Tags: c, function, visual-studio-code, compilation, header-files

I creating a program in c language and i using the Visual Studio Code for the first time, my functions in the header files don't function. This is my code in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "PilhaDinamica.h"
#include "PilhaEstatica.h"

int main()
{
    Pilha *p = criaPilha();
    
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my .h file:

```
#ifndef PILHADINAMICA_H_INCLUDED
#define PILHADINAMICA_H_INCLUDED


typedef struct Nodo{
    char info;
    struct Nodo*prox;
} nodo;

typedef struct {
    nodo * Topo;
} Pilha;

Pilha * criaPilha();
int pilha_vazia(Pilha *p);
void push(Pilha *p, char times);
char pop(Pilha *p);
#endif
```

This is my file with the functions:

```
#include "PilhaDinamica.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
  
Pilha *criaPilha()
{
    Pilha *p = (Pilha*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->Topo = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

And this is shown in my output: "...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmjk1nS.o:main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `criaPilha'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

what can i do to make it compile correctly?

Comment: Include both object file for `PilhaDinamica.c` in the linker command line.  Not a problem with the headers at all — you're just not telling the compiler/linker what to link to create the complete program.  Headers are not designed to provide the information to the compiler/linker on what to link — they merely specify what's available to be used if you link the code correctly.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure you're not using Visual Studio, instead? I've never seen someone use MSVC with VSCode (though it's possible).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do I have to specify the file 'PilhaDinamica.c' in the header of my 'main.c'?

Comment: @LHLaurini, Yes i using the Vs code. I started using it today, until then I used code blocks

Comment: No.  You need to compile `PilhaDinamica.c` to an object file, `PilhaDinamica.obj` on Windows or `PilhaDinamica.o` most other places, and then in the operation which creates the executable, you need to specify both `main.obj` and `PilhaDinamica.obj` as arguments (before listing any libraries).  How you do that depends on whether you're using an IDE (and which one you're using) or whether you're using a `makefile`, or building some other way.  In the short term, you could `#include "PilhaDinamica.c"` but that is pretty much cheating and definitely not recommended.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It finally worked, thanks a lot!! I included "PilhaDinamica.c" and it worked, but I will study creating the .obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, header files (*.h) contains declarations (type, variable and function declarations) and source files (*.c) the definitions of those declarations.

At the compilation step, only source files will be compiled (because the definitions are there). A program or library creation is a 2 (actually more, like preprocessing and more but for simplicity we keep it at 2) step process:

1. creating object files

e.g. `gcc -c -o object_file_name.o source_file_name.c`

2. link those object files into an executable or static/shared library

e.g. `gcc -o program_or_library_name object_file_1.o object_file_2.o ...`

So, in your case you have to call the compiler two times for your source files (with the -c flag) and once to link those created object files into an executable.

**Note:** If you're using a different compiler other than `gcc`, have a look at the documentation on how to create object files and link them together.

Comment: i made and function verry thanks, but i have a question, I just need to create the object only at the beginning of my project, or every time I make any changes?

Comment: Whenever you change your source code, you'll have to create a new object file. Think it as this way, your source code is written in human readable language (C), the object file is written in machine readable language (assembler). To reflect the changes you'll need a new translation.